# Creating a audit trigger which update a audit table automatically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle19c

My tables are

`Book`

```
CREATE TABLE Book 
(
    Bk_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
    BK_Name VARCHAR(60)NOT NULL,
    Author VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
    Price NUMERIC(03)NOT NULL,
    No_of_copies NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Book_PK PRIMARY KEY (Bk_id) 
);
```

`Location`

```
CREATE TABLE Location 
(
    Loc_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
    Loc_Name VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    Stock NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Location_PK PRIMARY KEY (Loc_id)
);
```

`Customer`

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    Cus_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL, 
    Cus_Name VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,  
    Gender VARCHAR(06)NOT NULL, 
    TP CHAR(12)NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (Cus_id)
);
```

`Copy`

```
CREATE TABLE Copy 
(
Copy_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
Bk_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
Loc_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
Opinion CHAR(02)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Copy PRIMARY KEY (Copy_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_Copy_Bk_id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Bk_id) REFERENCES Book(Bk_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_Copy_Loc_id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Loc_id) REFERENCES Location(Loc_id)
);
```

`Borrow`

```
CREATE TABLE Borrow 
(
    Cus_evo NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL,
    B_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    R_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Fee NUMERIC(03)NOT NULL,
    Copy_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
    Cus_id CHAR(06)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Borrow PRIMARY KEY (Cus_id,Copy_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Borrow_Copy_id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Copy_id) REFERENCES Copy(Copy_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Borrow_Cus_id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Cus_id) REFERENCES Customer(Cus_id)
);
```

`Audit_Table`

```
Create table Audit_Table
(
Cus_Name VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,
BK_Name VARCHAR(60)NOT NULL,
B_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Loc_Name VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL,
Cus_evo NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL
);
```

If a customer gives a zero evaluation`Cus_evo=0`, the details of their Borrowing (`Cus_Name` from `CUSTOMER`, the `BK_Name` from `Book`, `B_Date` from `Borrow`, `Loc_Name` of the copy from `Location` and `Cus_evo` from `Borrow`) must be placed in an audit table.

The trigger that I created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TRIGGER"
BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE ON Borrow
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Cus_evo=0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Audit_Table
VALUES (:OLD.Cus_Name, :OLD.BK_Name, :OLD.B_Date, :OLD.Loc_Name, :OLD.Cus_evo);
END;
/
```

I get this error:

> Errors: TRIGGER AUDIT_TRIGGER
> Line/Col: 3/9 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.CUS_NAME'
> Line/Col: 3/24 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.BK_NAME'
> Line/Col: 3/51 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.LOC_NAME'

Comment: When creating table Borrow we need table Copy. Without table Copy you get an error.

Comment: Your trigger and as modified by @VBoka fails on INSERT.  When a trigger fires on insert there are no values in the OLD Pseudo record - all columns are NULL. See the section "About OLD and NEW Pseudorecords" in the [2 Day Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG50000)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not use old and new values from other tables only from table Borrwo when you are creating trigger
2. You need to specify if you want to check new or old value in WHEN clause

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TRIGGER"
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Borrow --I have removed double quotes
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.Cus_evo = 0) -- I have added new. before the name of the column
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Audit_Table
        VALUES (:OLD.Fee, :OLD.Copy_id, :OLD.Cus_id, :OLD.B_Date, :OLD.Cus_evo);
        -- I have replaced column names from other tables with column names 
        -- from table "Borrow"
   END;
   /
   ```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1cfd505fc623a896d08e90c41a6cbb88)

In this demo I have removed

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Borrow_Copy_id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Copy_id) REFERENCES Copy(Copy_id),
```

from table Borrow spec because it references on the table Copy that we do not have here in your question.

After I have read the comment from @Belayer I have concluded you will need two triggers like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT ON Borrow
FOR EACH ROW
when (new.Cus_evo = 0) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Audit_Table
    VALUES (:new.Copy_id, :new.Copy_id, :new.B_Date, :new.Cus_id, :new.Cus_evo);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TRIGGER2"
BEFORE UPDATE ON Borrow
FOR EACH ROW
when (OLD.Cus_evo = 0) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Audit_Table
    VALUES (:OLD.Copy_id, :OLD.Copy_id, :OLD.B_Date, :OLD.Cus_id, :OLD.Cus_evo);
END;
/
```

Here is a demo with demonstration:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82dbf63c18b98596889be8cf0cbbfc02)

Comment: Hi @Belayer , thank you for your comment, I have updated y asnwer.

Comment: Hi @TharinduChathuranga , is this answer of any help to you ?

Comment: I update the question could you please recheck it?

Comment: Hi @TharinduChathuranga first analyze my answer. You can not use :OLD.Cus_Name becuase it is a column from table Audit_Table and you can use only old values from table you are building the trigger for. Also, read the comment from Balayer . Again, read my whole answer....